# Is $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ an euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

> Is $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$ ($p\in \mathbb{N}$ prime) an euclidean domain?

I think that the answer is not, but i can't prove it.

I only can prove it is an unique factorization domain

Comment: Localization of a euclidean ring always gives a euclidean ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a Euclidean domain. As was noted in a comment, localization of a euclidean domain is euclidean. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44955/reference-request-number-theory-of-z1-p) for more detailed answer by Pete L. Clark.